# JHipster app looks different in production profile

Tags: jhipster

I'm working on a JHipster app :

```
* JHipster 6.8.0 (monolith)
* PostgreSQL
* Vuejs blueprint
* Bootswatch flatly theme
```

I've managed to deploy it on Heroku (Dyno formation + Postgre Hobby dev) using the sub-generator but then I realized that my app was looking different from the dev mode.

So what I did was running a local build of my app in production mode, and then I was able to reproduce.

First issue, I had some CSP issues regarding Google Fonts, I've managed to fix the errors in the browser console by following this tip : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10116/files but still the application looks different :

When I inspect an element, in dev mode I have :

```
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
```

In production mode :

```
font-family: Lato,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol;
```

In this case, I suppose that production mode is correct as Flatly theme uses Google Fonts.

Second issue, for some reason, the style on the "card" css class is different between dev and production, in dev mode :

```
card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

In production mode :

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

In that case, dev mode is correct as I don't what that border.

FYI : I have some CSS tweaks in vendor.scss, but nothing related to this and those tweaks work fine in both profiles. Webpack config is untouched.

So it seems that I have CSS differences between profiles, I'd like to have a consistent UI, what should I check to try to fix this ?

Any thoughts ?
Thanks.

Comment: There was a related issue in the Vue blueprint recently, try making the change from this PR: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/pull/611/files

Comment: Thanks for the tip but my webpack prod already has this fix. I also have this as last attribute in HtmlWebpackPlugin : `// necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'`

Comment: I've commented out chunksSortMode: 'dependency' and it solved my problem. I haven't noticed any side effects so far so we'll see :)